# How to DRY similar function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function I want to call in a javascript plugin:

```
var display = function(overlay, overlay_color, modal, opacity, drag)    {
      //some stuff
}
```

---

I am currently calling this function like this:

```
if (ajax) {
    modal.waitUntilExists(function() {
        load();
        display($("#lean_overlay"), options.overlay_color, $(options.modal_id), options.overlay, options.drag);
    });
} else {
     display($("#lean_overlay"), options.overlay_color, $(options.modal_id), options.modal, options.overlay, options.drag);
}
```

The question is how can I DRY the triggering of the `display` function? I was thinking about splitting the function into a `init` and `fire` methods (not sure if the right terminology) - to call the method once, and fire accordingly.

Any info will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Your 2nd call has one parameter too many.

Comment: Thanks! Will amend this!

Comment: Is this a function that should create a Dom element? If so I would recommend using a Widget from jQuery mobile:http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/   Otherwise creating a Class would be good. The init part of the function could be the constructor and the fire function a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a function often with (partly) the same parameters, you can use a [partial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). Since functions are first class citizens in Javascript, it is excellent for doing this [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

In your case you can create one before the if statement:

```
var partial = display.bind(null,
                           $("#lean_overlay"),
                           options.overlay_color, 
                           $(options.modal_id),
                           options.overlay,
                           options.drag);
```

And then use the newly created `partial()`

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/07/20/partially-applied-functions-in-javascript/

PS "partial" is a horrible function name, [unless the function returns a partial](http://mochi.github.io/mochikit/doc/html/MochiKit/Base.html#fn-partial). Use something better that describes what the partial does, like your "fire".

Comment: Thanks Chris - will have a look into this!

Comment: @Rich Peck: Have fun. I also found a [question on this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8100354/383793). A lot of resources on functional programming have a mathematical nature. Mathematicians are even worse in naming functions than I am. They do get bonus points for brevity with their single letter names. Don't let that scare you. Functional programming has its merits.

Comment: LOL thanks for the heads-up! I will be looking at this shortly

Comment: This was exactly what was required - thank you again